# How to take sample from pyspark dataframe by column?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have very large pyspark with two columns of interest : `date` column and `id` column. Dataframe is partitioned by `date`. I want to take a sample from that dataset, such that if some `id` is in the sample, then all rows with that `id` should be in the sample.

I can think of the following method:

```
id_df = df[['id']].sample(fraction = 0.001) # can be duplicates, ok for now

sampled_df = id_df.join(df, on='id')
```

Is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: will you be able to update some mock data. few line will give us better look into your requirement. please provide, what you have and what should be the expected output

Comment: Sample on the `id` . Findout the distinct `id` values. Join this distinct `id` dataframe with original dataframe.

Comment: Here's somewhat working code. https://pastebin.com/UMGUXv5C